# NetworkManager service doesn't update resolv.conf with the DNS servers

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, virtualbox

Using **Kali Linux** in **MacOS** (**Macbook pro 16inch intel i9**) with pre-built image of Kali Linux for **VirtualBox** virtual machine - https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines. Network configured as **NAT**.

I am trying to configure my desired DNS server (Cloudflare `1.1.1.1` in that case).

The steps I did:

1. Modifiying `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` - remove the hash key (`#`) from `prepend domain-name-servers` and change it to `prepend domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1;`.
2. Running `service NetworkManager restart` (as **root** user).

Doing the mentioned actions, I expect `/etc/resolv.conf` that is generated by the **NetworkManager** to include `1.1.1.1` at the top of the name servers list.

The actual result is that nothing is changed but I still have my ISP default DNS servers.

Comment: Maybe this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/224966/how-do-i-get-resolvconf-to-regenerate-resolv-conf-after-i-change-etc-network-in

Comment: @BlockchainOffice I already search for an answer for my query and found many like that. It tells you a different way on how to configure your DNS servers. I am familiar with that way and to the best of my knowledge it should work. I need to understand what am I doing wrong using this particular method.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do the change:

0.) Be sure you have direct connection because interface will be deactivated and activated so you lose your remote connection if you have.

1.) Open "nmtui"

```
sudo nmtui
```

2.) "Edit a connection"

3.) "Edit" the questioning interface

4.) "Add" 1.1.1.1 as DNS server

5.) Hit "OK" and Hit "Back"

6.) "Activate Connection"

7.) Be sure you're on your proper interface and hit "Deactivate"

8.) Be sure you're on your proper interface and hit "Activate"

9.) Hit "Back"

10.) Hit "Quit"

11.) Check the result

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Indeed, when NetworkManager uses dhclient as backend, it provides it an alternate configuration file using `-cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-someuuid-someinterface.conf` instead of the original: configuration has to be done to NM, not dhclient.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I am not looking for an alternative to use, rather than an explanation why doesn't my solution work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After performing some research myself - seems that configuring `prepend domain-name-servers` in the `dhclient.conf` file is broken and currently isn't affecting `resolv.conf` as it should.
Here is a video addressing the issue and suggesting a proper solution:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArsErSR-U4E